# How to update my app in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, development-environment

I know this may sound like a dumb question, but how do I update my app in eclipse?  I went through the process of exporting a signed app, but now I want to add some ads.  do I need to go through the signing process again?  I'm confused, because I tried to do it but when I uploaded it to google play they gave me an error message.  So please, can someone give me step by step instructions on how to do this without having to upload an entire new apk?

Comment: You have to make signed package again, if you change anything in your code .

Comment: And what error did you get?

Comment: Did you sign it with the same key ?

Comment: Again, everyone is telling me what to do, and not showing me what to do...Where do I actually go (what buttons do I push in Eclipse?)  I went to Android Tools > Export Signed Application Package > Select Use Existing keystore (put in password) >  Select using existing alias (put in passowrd) > (it is here where the problem exists.)  The destination and key/certificate dialog box says certificate already exists and gives this long instruction that the certificate doesn't expire for 25 years.  What do I do with this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of your versions for your app.

On every new version you make, make sure you update your app version from manifest.

Ofcourse you have to keep your keystore and remember your passwords you set for the app you uploaded to the store.

And yes on every change you want to make you do it in eclipse, update your version number and export it as signed apk, and upload that last version to the store

Comment: Again ppl are telling me what to do and not SHOWING me.  What buttons should i push, what selections should I make?  And what is a keystore?  I didn't put any values in for this...all i did was put a name a password my city, country, alias, certificate expiration, etc...that's it.

Comment: What i told you is the exact proccess. There is nothing else to press. 

You already went from the sign apk process as you said. That  implies that you already generated a new keystore with your app, and you already set your passwords. 

The process of updating the app is nothing new. You change the app version as i said and make the changed you want. 

You asked for instructions and i gave you some. And you already did them so you can do them again

Comment: Walk me through the export process please.  I keep getting this warning "Destination file already exists."

Comment: The warning message is pretty straight forward. http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Signing_and_Preparing_an_Android_Application_for_Release

Answer (score 0):

Every iteration of your app to Google Play requires exporting and uploading a signed apk.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign any updates. Even more, you need to sign it with the SAME KEY if you want to update an existing package.

From https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en

> Update your apps
>
> Preparing your APK
>
> When the time comes to make changes to your APK, be sure to update
>   your app’s Version Code as well so that existing users will receive
>   the new content. Please use the following checklist to make sure your
>   new APK is ready to update your existing users:
>
> - The Package Name of the updated APK needs to be the same as the
>     current version.
> - The Version Code needs to be greater than that
>     current version.
> - The
>     updated APK needs to be signed with the same signature as the current
>     version.